# SVM classification

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, linear

I have a small data set of 450 instances with feature vector of 21 feature and and I need to classify (binary classification) I applied Support Vector Machine Kernel Linear and RBF. In my case RBF perform poor and Linear kernel perform better. Can anybody suggest why is it the case? Although as we know RBF do perform better.

---

I did optimization for C and gamma and found that C=1 and gamma= 0.7 is best otherwise either the accuracy is same or it get worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RBF kernel doesn't necessarily perform better. That only applies *after* you've optimized all hyperparameters and even then the difference is often only marginal. That said, for low-dimensional problems like yours, the RBF kernel is likely to yield better models.

A few points:

1. You have to optimize hyperparameters when using SVM, which is $C$ (and $\gamma$ if you use the RBF kernel). How did you optimize them? I recommend having a look at [Optunity](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/notebooks/notebooks/sklearn-svc.html) for this task.
2. You should standardize all features to a given interval, e.g. $[0,1]$, to make sure distances are not biased towards features on a large scale compared to others.

Comment: Thanks for telling about Optunity it provides really better results.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on how the decision boundary exists in the training data.In your case the decision boundary was linear in nature and hence linearn kernel did better than rbf.Following is an [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html) on how to visualize decision boundary atleast for limited features.

[image: SVM decision boundaries]